# How I create an Erlang app using rebar3 in shell?

Tags: erlang, rebar3

We can create application using rebar as below:

```
rebar create-app appid=demo
```

But when execute `rebar3 create-app appid=demo`in shell, an exception occurred as below:

```
➜  transaction_publish_service git:(master) rebar3 create-app appid=mqttcli  
===> Command 'create-app' not found
```

So, if `create-app` was removed in rebar3, which command can replace it?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent in rebar3 is `new`. Use

```
rebar3 new app demo
```

More information about this can be found in [documentation](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/basic-usage).